# Azure App Service Authentication with Google oAuth 2.0 Bearer Token

Tags: google-oauth, azure-web-app-service, service-accounts, bearer-token

We are using App Service Authentication to protect a web API and using Google as authentication provider. It works as expected when we fire a request from a browser (when the session information is in the cookie)

IIS log:

> 2016-05-29T13:51:19  PID[3600] Verbose     Received request: GET
>   https://XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/user 2016-05-29T13:51:19 
>   PID[3600] Verbose     Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site
>   'XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 728. 2016-05-29T13:51:19 
>   PID[3600] Verbose     Authenticated XXXXXX@gmail.com successfully
>   using 'Session Cookie' authentication.

But when we use API testing tool such as Postman and set the *Authorization* header with bearer token, it always results in redirection.

IIS log:

> 2016-05-29T13:53:38  PID[3600] Verbose     Received request: POST
>   https://XXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/user 2016-05-29T13:53:38 
>   PID[3600] Information Redirecting:
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXX-XXXXX7attpunn9smo4.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=openid+profile+email&state=nonce%3De5f4aabe11cb4544bf18d00920940d47_20160529135838%26redir%3D%2Fapi%2Fuser

We also tried to set *X-ZUMO-AUTH* header with the same bearer token, we see error as the token is not in expected format. Apparently it expects encoded JWT token.

IIS log:

> 016-05-29T13:51:52  PID[3600] Verbose     Received request: POST
>   https://XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/user 2016-05-29T13:51:52 
>   PID[3600] Warning     JWT validation failed: IDX10708:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this
>   string: 'Bearer
>   ya29.XXXXXXXXXX_RDrX_zsuvMx49e_9QS5ECz9F1yhDHe5j4H9gRN6opkjLXvN1IJZjHXa_Q'.
>   The string needs to be in compact JSON format, which is of the form:
>   '..'.. 2016-05-29T13:51:52  PID[3600]
>   Information Redirecting:
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXXX-k5nj6dkf987attpunn9smo4.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=openid+profile+email&state=nonce%3De15b0915406142378XXXXX_20160529135652%26redir%3D%2Fapi%2Fuser

Note:
Bearer token obtained from Google is valid as we can verify the detail by making call to 
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=[token]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The Google token you're using is an access token, not a bearer token. It can be used to access Google resources but cannot be used to authenticate with your Web API.

I wasn't able to find good documentation on this, but I can tell you it works here instead:

1. In your client app, you must obtain an **id_token** and an **authorization code** from Google. You normally get this when the user logs in using the Google OpenID Connect login. I assume you already know how to do this since you already know how to get the access token.
2. Send a POST request to **https://{hostname}/.auth/login/google** with a JSON payload that looks like `{"authorization_code":"<code>", "id_token":"<id_token>"}`.
3. A successful login response will contain a JSON payload that contains an authenticationToken field. Cache this token.
4. You can use the authentication token from #3 to make authenticated calls to your web API. Put it in the x-zumo-auth HTTP request header.

Comment: Chris, we never get to the step# 3 because the server returns internal server error.

Comment: With Google we get auth_code first then use it to get id_token in subsequent requests. 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow
IIS Log:

Warning     Call to HTTP endpoint https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed: 400 (Bad Request). Partial response: {
 "error": "invalid_grant",
 "error_description": "Code was already redeemed."
}
..This can also happen if a previously-used authentication code is replayed.

Comment: The error makes sense. Can you use an auth flow with Google that returns you an authorization code and an id_token in one response?  For example "response_type=code id_token"? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters. Or if you're using Android, is it possible to acquire both the auth_code and the id_token independently via some Android API calls?

Comment: I was able to get the code and id_token in one response. But when I call https://{hostname}/.auth/login/google with the expected payload, I get the following error about invalid issuer. (https:// vs without )

JWT validation failed: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'accounts.google.com'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'https://accounts.google.com' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'null'

Comment: That's odd. From the error message you showed the two issuers seem to match. Can you clarify what you mean by "https:// vs without"?

Comment: @chris-gallam, it's the formatting that messes up the url
Actual error message is : 
JWT validation failed: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '<accounts.google.com>'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: <https:// accounts.google.com> or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'null'

Comment: Ah, I see. Is this an old Google application or a new one? Also, how are you acquiring the id_token?

Comment: I am getting the id_token by making GET call to < https:// accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth> with response_type=code id_token. 
Refering to this [article](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow). It also says: "The Issuer Identifier for the Issuer of the response. Always <https:// accounts.google.com> or <accounts.google.com> for Google ID tokens"

Comment: Interesting. In this case it seems Google is sometimes not consistent in it's OpenID Connect implementation. Either way this is a bug we need to fix on the App Service side based on the documentation you've provided. Please give us a few days and we'll get our validation logic corrected. Thanks for hanging in there and answering all my questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on Authentication / Authorization from App Service Portal
2. Browse to the web app or API that requires authentication, you will be redirected to google login page, when you authenticate successfully, the response will contain:

   - "id_token": this token can be extracted from the response, or by accessing the Token Store  /.auth/me
   - "redirect_uri" this token will be included in the response body, also you can just set it statically in the following step since this is the callback URL and it shouldn't change unless you change it from the google console
3. POST a request to  https://{hostname}/.auth/login/google with the following JSON payload,  {"redirect_uri":"", "id_token":""}.  a successful response will contain "authenticationToken" store this token or cache it
4. Subsequent requests to the APIs that requires authentication should contain an HTTP request header:

   "x-zumo-auth" with the value of "authenitcationToken"

**Bonus:** 
In order to verify your token you can POST to https://{hostname}/.auth/login/google  with the following JSON pay load {"id_token":""}, the response should specify if the token is valid or not