# Azure App Services POST Access token for AuthenticationToken fails for everything but Facebook

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

According to the documentation ([documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/)) :

> Your application can trigger the same redirect itself by navigating the user to the /.auth/login/ endpoint of your site, where  is one of aad, facebook, google, microsoftaccount, and twitter. This option is perfect for sites featuring a login button and for many mobile applications.
>
> Alternatively, a client can obtain a token using a provider SDK and exchange it for a session token. Simply submit an HTTP POST to the same endpoint with the provider token in a JSON body under the key “access_token” (or “authenticationToken” for Microsoft Account). This is the preferred solution for mobile applications if a provider SDK is available on the platform, and it also works for many web and API applications.

I have found this **ONLY** works with a facebook token.  I am able to authenticate with google, facebook, twitter, and microsoft account by hitting the normal /.auth/login/{provider} endpoint.  However if you attempt to POST the resulting token from as discovered from the .auth/me endpoint or from the HTTP Headers (e.g. X-MS-TOKEN-GOOGLE-ACCESS-TOKEN, etc.) the POST endpoint only works for Facebook.

I discovered the following:

- **Google** - you'll get a HTTP/1.1 400 'authorization_code' field is required. if you follow the documentation.  However when changing the "access_token" name to "authorization_code" causes a 500 Internal Server Error
- **Twitter** - undisclosed in the documentation requires an "access_token_secret" value in the payload in addition to the "access_token" value.  However including this only results in a Unauthorized 401 results - which seems to be a bug since the facebook payload works so the controller shouldn't required auth already
- **Microsoft account** - Same Unauthorized 401 Error as Twitter.

Comment: EDIT - i've resolved Twitter and Microsoft.  Google is still busted.


1. json payload MUST include quotes around the property names.
2. For Twitter - the undocumented access_token_secret must be included
3. For Microsoft - the documented “authenticationToken” for Microsoft... appears to be wrong.  It only worked for me with "access_token" included for the token.


Sadly I have no solution for Google.

Comment: Microsoft Account supports using either access_token or authenticationToken. If authenticationToken is not working for you, I suggest you enable application logging to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for client-directed logins is unfortunately lacking. Take a look at the following post to learn how Google login works when using the client-directed flow:

[Azure App Service Authentication with Google oAuth 2.0 Bearer Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518982/azure-app-service-authentication-with-google-oauth-2-0-bearer-token/37550687#37550687)

In particular, you are required to send **both** an *id_token* and an *authorization_code* value in the JSON payload. These values must be acquired from Google as part of a user login.